# Subclassing RichEdit control causes text to no longer display

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, subclass, gdi

I tried subclassing the RichtextEdit control MSFTEDIT_CLASS to implement a custom colour for highlighting any selected text.

```
// subclass the rich edit control
SetWindowSubclass(hwndEdit, RichEditSubclassProc, 0, 0);
```

I used this procedure. I get a red highlight and no text. Any ideas?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK RichEditSubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    static HBRUSH hCustomBrush = NULL;
    static COLORREF customColor = RGB(255, 0, 0); // set custom color to red for example

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // get the selection range
        CHARRANGE selRange;
        SendMessage(hWnd, EM_EXGETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&selRange);

        // get the DC for the rich edit control
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        if (selRange.cpMin != selRange.cpMax)
        {
            // create custom brush if it doesn't exist yet
            if (!hCustomBrush)
            {
                hCustomBrush = CreateSolidBrush(customColor);
            }

            // set the background mode to transparent
            SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);

            // set the custom brush as the background brush
            HBRUSH hPrevBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hDC, hCustomBrush);

            // get the bounding rectangles for the selection
            RECT selStartRect, selEndRect;
            SendMessage(hWnd, EM_GETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&selStartRect);
            SendMessage(hWnd, EM_GETRECT, 0, (LPARAM)&selEndRect);

            // adjust the selection rectangles to the client area
            RECT clientRect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRect);
            OffsetRect(&selStartRect, -ps.rcPaint.left, -ps.rcPaint.top);
            OffsetRect(&selEndRect, -ps.rcPaint.left, -ps.rcPaint.top);
            IntersectRect(&selStartRect, &selStartRect, &clientRect);
            IntersectRect(&selEndRect, &selEndRect, &clientRect);

            // fill the background of the selected text with the custom brush
            FillRect(hDC, &selStartRect, hCustomBrush);
            FillRect(hDC, &selEndRect, hCustomBrush);

            // restore the previous background brush
            SelectObject(hDC, hPrevBrush);
        }

        // call the default painting function
        DefSubclassProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

        // release the DC for the rich edit control
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My idea is to create a custom richedit box where the user can select any highlight colour. It seems the newer version of the Richedit control simply won't change the colour of highlighted text (backcolour) in spite of any attempts. It keeps defaulting to the system highlight.

Comment: That reads like a heavy-handed approach at customizing a Rich Edit control. I guess you should instead be sending an [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcharformat) message instead of fiddling with the rendering code.

Comment: I've tried CHARFORMAT2 CHARFORMAT2W/A and the rest of the family. I can set the color of the text background if I select something from my routine. It seems the RichText control still does not keep a property with any set colours. It always defaults to the system highlight colour. Meaning I can set a highlight from my program, I can't set one for the user. It won't keep the setting. I have tried subclassing like above, masking, using system colours to no avail. I can set a highlight with the Windows structs. I could post that here too. It just keeps reverting to default in the box. What a pity

Comment: My guess would be, calling `BeginPaint` a second time in a row without an intervening `EndPaint` fails. You call `BeginPaint`, and then forward to the original window proc that calls `BeginPaint` again, and fails to acquire the `HDC` on which to paint.

Comment: In any case, I suspect this approach is hopeless. Whatever you manage to paint before forwarding to the original procedure, will be wiped out and painted over. If you try to forward first and then paint on top, it would be difficult to preserve the text.